# Hide response after an Ajax process

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

After a first Ajax process, I want to hide  answer when user clicks again in a text field. I can not find the correct syntax. Could you help me?

Here is my simplified code...

```
$('#address').keyup(function () 
{
    $('#check-address').hide();
}); 
$('#address').change(function () 
{
    $('#check-address').hide();
    $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
    ...
        $('#check-address').show();
        $('#check-address').html(response.correct);
        $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
    ...
    });
});
```

EDIT

Here is more code...

```
$('#address').keyup(function () 
{
    $('#check-address').hide();
}); 
$('#address').change(function () 
{
    $('#check-address').hide();
    $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',               
        data: 'address=' + $('#address').val(),
        //data: 'address=' + $.trim($('#address').val()),
        url: 'process-address.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) 
        {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            if (response.result == 1) 
            {
                $('#check-address').show();
                $('#check-address').html(response.correct);
                $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
                $('#submit').button('enable');
            }
            elseif 
            {
                /***/
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your great explanations. :)

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

attach a click event handler in the ajax response

```
$.ajax({
    ...
        $('#check-address').show();
        $('#check-address').html(response.correct);
        $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
         //bind the click handler here to what ever you want to hide probably you can use .one
    ...
    });
```

EDIT

> hide answer when user clicks again in a text field.

i assume you mean any text field?

```
 $.ajax({
        ...
            $('#check-address').show();
            $('#check-address').html(response.correct);
            $('#check-address').listview('refresh');
            $(":text").click(function(){$("#answer").hide();});
        ...
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you suggest me to use `$('#address').bind("change", function (event)` instead of `$('#address').change(function ()`?

Comment: no the are one and the same thing, can you clarify what do you mean by "hide answer" what is the answer in the code you have provided

Comment: So I solve my problem with a button "reset"... This method is more traditional, but perhaps simpler to the user.